# JBOSS 7.4 --> 7.4.6 does not start

Tags: java, java-8, jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x

**Hi, I have a problem after updating jboss EAP to version 7.4.6, the server does not start.
before the update, the server was booting up**

System:

RHL8

openjdk version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)

installed by :

java -jar jboss-eap-7.4.0-installer.jar

patch applied by CLI (patch apply)

JBoss EAP cumulative patch ID is: jboss-eap-7.4.6.CP, one-off patches include: none

start jboss

$EAP_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml -Djboss.bind.address=10.10.45.80 -Djboss.bind.address.management=10.10.45.80

```
12:28:26,857 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ManagementRealm",
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.management.http.extensible is missing [org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ManagementRealm]",
        "jboss.remoting.remoting-http-upgrade-service.http-management is missing [org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ManagementRealm, jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management]"
    ]
}



12:28:26,885 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "remoting"),
    ("http-connector" => "http-remoting-connector")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ApplicationRealm"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.remoting.remoting-http-upgrade-service.http-remoting-connector is missing [org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ApplicationRealm]"]
}



12:28:26,886 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "security"),
    ("security-domain" => "other")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.security.security-management",
        "jboss.security.jaas"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.security.security-domain.other is missing [jboss.security.jaas, jboss.security.security-management]"]
}



12:28:26,886 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "security"),
    ("security-domain" => "jboss-web-policy")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.security.security-management",
        "jboss.security.jaas"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.security.security-domain.jboss-web-policy is missing [jboss.security.jaas, jboss.security.security-management]"]
}



12:28:26,886 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "security"),
    ("security-domain" => "jaspitest")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.security.security-management",
        "jboss.security.jaas"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.security.security-domain.jaspitest is missing [jboss.security.jaas, jboss.security.security-management]"]
}



12:28:26,886 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "security"),
    ("security-domain" => "jboss-ejb-policy")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.security.security-management",
        "jboss.security.jaas"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.security.security-domain.jboss-ejb-policy is missing [jboss.security.jaas, jboss.security.security-management]"]
}



12:28:26,887 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("https-listener" => "https")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ApplicationRealm"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["org.wildfly.undertow.listener.https is missing [org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ApplicationRealm]"]
}



12:28:26,887 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("host" => "default-host"),
    ("setting" => "http-invoker")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ApplicationRealm"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["org.wildfly.undertow.http-invoker.host.default-host.http-invoker is missing [org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ApplicationRealm]"]
}



12:28:26,887 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("security-realm" => "ManagementRealm")
]) - failure description: "WFLYDM0145: The resource 'security-realm' is unsupported since Java 14"



12:28:26,888 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0459: Triggering roll back due to missing management services.
12:28:26,888 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ManagementRealm",
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.management.http.extensible is missing [org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ManagementRealm]",
        "jboss.remoting.remoting-http-upgrade-service.http-management is missing [org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.ManagementRealm, jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management]"
```

Comment: I'm almost sure that EAP7.4.x doesn't run on openjdk version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22. It may run on Java 17 if you are using elytron and not the 'legacy' security realms.

Comment: Did you also upgrade to a Java version that will not be supported in 2 weeks?

Comment: @ehsavoie 

thanks, you were partially right
according to the documentation, jboss only supports openjdk redhat

Comment: Having the same problem... want to upgrade from **Java 11** to **17** (OpenJDK). While **EAP 7.4.0** starts properly... **7.4.6** refuses to start with these errors. The `standalone.xml` itself has not changed.

Comment: The problem starts with 7.4.4... tried all single patches one by one. I can't find an easy to follow migration guide and would expect an untouched JBoss EAP to run out of the box – a shame that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

OpenJDK17 is only supported starting with JBoss EAP version 7.4.7: https://access.redhat.com/articles/2026253

Here is an article describing specifically some changes related to security which need to be applied in order for JBoss to work with JDK17: https://access.redhat.com/articles/6956863